# Deleting rows that have same value in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset ...i have filtered out data that i don't want to use. Now i want to remove the common columns from the original dataset that are in the filtered dataset(i don't want to use)...i cannot put dataset here because its quite big. i have looked for some solution on StackOverflow but it didn't help.

Columns :

`id   url     region  region_url  price`

i want to remove price which has zero...

Comment: fields with zero price have already been filtered

Comment: You can use simple filter like this `df[df["price"] > 0]`. can you be more specific to issue? title and your question is not same

Comment: i only want to find a possible way in which i can just delete the common rows in two datasets